# syntax error with command vaccum

Tags: sqlite

I get a syntax error:

```
/tmp> sqlite3 -version
3.18.0 2017-03-28 18:48:43 424a0d380332858ee55bdebc4af3789f74e70a2b3ba1cf29d84b9b4bcf3e2e37
/tmp> sqlite3 cpms-access-2.db 'vaccum;'
Error: near "vaccum": syntax error
```

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) I can't figure out why it should completely fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vaccum;  -- what you tried
vacuum;  -- correct spelling
   ^
```